# package javax.jnlp does not exist error when i compile JNLP

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

I am using build file to compile my project. I am getting `package javax.jnlp does not exist` error. My java file doesnot have any errors. I have added `javaws.jar` to my project build path.

My build file code

```
<!-- Build file for the project. -->
<project basedir="." default="launch" name="OPRS_JNLP">

  <target name="properties">
    <property name="build" value="build" />
    <property name="dist" value="dist" />
    <property name="src" value="src" />

    <property
      name="classpath"
      value="${java.home}/jre/lib/javaws.jar" />
  </target>

  <target
    name="compile"
    depends="properties"
    description="Compile the project" >
    <mkdir dir="${build}/share" />
    <javac
      debug="on"
      destdir="${build}/share"
      srcdir="com/abhibus/oprs"
      source="1.6"
      classpath="${classpath}" />
    <copy todir="${build}/share">
      <fileset dir="com/abhibus/oprs">
        <exclude name="**/CVS" />
        <exclude name="**/*.java" />
      </fileset>
    </copy>
  </target>

  <target
    name="dist"
    depends="compile"
    description="Create project distribution" >
    <mkdir dir="${build}/jar" />
    <mkdir dir="${build}/jar/lib" />
    <jar destfile="${build}/jar/apsrtcoprs.jar">
      <fileset dir="${build}/share">
        <include name="**/*.class" />
      </fileset>
    </jar>
  </target>

  <target
    name="make-launch-file"
    depends="properties"
    description="Copies and configures the launch file" >
    <copy todir="${build}/jar" >
      <fileset dir="${src}/conf" >
        <include name="**/*.jnlp" />
      </fileset>
    </copy>
  </target>

  <target
    name="launch"
    depends="dist, make-launch-file"
    description="Launch the project using webstart">
    <exec executable="javaws"
      dir="${build}/jar">
      <arg line="-codebase file:. file:./apsrtcoprs.jnlp" />
    </exec>
  </target>

  <target
    name="uninstall"
    depends="properties"
    description="Uninstall the project from the webstart cache">
    <exec executable="javaws">
      <arg
        line="-uninstall http://localhost:9999/apsrtcoprs.jnlp"
        />
    </exec>
  </target>

  <target name="clean"
    depends="properties"
    description="Clean all generated files">
      <delete dir="${build}" />
      <delete dir="${dist}" />
  </target>
</project>
```

What is going wrong ? When i searched through the forums they say to include the javaws.jar, which i have already done. how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Check the path.  Here it would be found by `java.home` of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6` added to `/lib/javaws.jar`.  More directly, try `${java.home}/lib/javaws.jar`

Comment: My Java hoem is pointing to /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_24/ and the actual path is /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_24/jre/lib where i have javaws.jar. I am refering to the same path here.

Comment: After modifying my classpath it compiles fine. But when i launch getting `Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "javaws" (in directory "/sreekanth/ProjectsCXF/JavaWebStartTest/src/build/jar"): java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory`. ?

Comment: That is a separate problem.  You should update this question with your answer and ask a new question.  Glad you got the first problem sorted.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At a guess, this:

```
value="${java.home}/jre/ib/javaws.jar" />
```

should be

```
value="${java.home}/jre/lib/javaws.jar" />
```

"lib", not "ib"

Comment: @user1103504: In that case I suggest you build in verbose mode to find out what value you're really including - it sounds like your `${java.home}` property isn't set properly... which could easily bite you later.

Answer (score 0):

this is somewhat weird.. I modified my classpath value as `/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_24/jre/lib/javaws.jar` and it is compiling. Thanks a lot Andrew and Jon for helping me.